# If $\tan(2x)=\frac{3}{4}$ and domain of $x =\left(0,\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$ find the value of $\tan(x)$

Tags: trigonometry, pi

How'd you approach this problem cause I was thinking about using an identity but I don't know how it'd be beneficial...

Thanks

Comment: Generally such problems can make use of [double angle formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Double-AngleFormulas.html) for trigonometric functions.

Comment: Please use the body of your Question to give a full statement of the problem you want help with.  Limiting the problem statement to the title of your post invites confusion by Readers, and the body of the Question gives plenty of room to clarify exactly what you are trying and why it doesn't seem to be working out.

Answer (score 2):

Start with identity

$${3\over 4}=\tan{2x}={2\tan{x}\over 1-\tan^2{x}}$$

This quadratic in $u=\tan{x}$ has two solutions

$$\tan{x}=-3$$
$$\tan{x}={1\over 3}$$

But $x\in [0,\pi/4]$ so we retain the second solution

$$x=\arctan{1\over 3}$$